# postgresql delete partition tables

Tags: function, postgresql, partition

I'm new at Postgresql and do not exactly know how to manage partition tables.
I have partition table based on day. Before inserting data, trigger checks date and put into corresponding child table.
eg.
11.15.2014 - insert into table named 11-15-2014_log.
11.16.2014 - insert into table named 11-16-2014_log.
Now I want to create function that will drop old child tables, for example, tables older than 90 days. 
Should I find and  drop child table according its tablename (cause it consists date of creation) OR should I find records older than 90 days in master table??
Any suggestion or hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing how much data you are processing or how often it is run, or even what language it is in makes it tricky to suggest anything. could you possibly show the trigger function that is creating the tables?

Comment: How big on average are each of these tables expected to be? i.e. do you really even *need* to partition them.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who ends up here looking for how to delete the table partitions in PostgreSQL, here is the modern answer.

The solution is not to use a DELETE statement because that will delete the data without dropping the corresponding table partitions that held the data. The OP asked about managing partition tables, not deleting records, so any solution using DELETE statements adds unnecessary database overhead of deleting records, leaves empty partition tables in place, and completely ignores one of the primary benefits of using partitioning; DROPing the table when it is no longer useful.

In this case the solution must be to DROP the no longer needed partition table. I have written a solution to resolve this issue in my production environment, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430686/postgresql-automating-deletion-of-old-partitions).

To resolve the OP's issue, the function I wrote can be used with two slight revisions to modify the **fullTablename** variable and the date format. The fullTablename variable line must be changed from

```
fullTablename := base_table_name || '_' || to_char(startTime, dateFormat);
```

to the YYYY-MM-DD_log format like this

```
fullTablename := to_char(startTime, dateFormat) || '_' || base_table_name;
```

Then the date format needs to be slightly modified from

```
WHEN partition_plan='day'   THEN 'YYYYDDD'
```

to the stated table naming convention

```
WHEN partition_plan='day'   THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Then the SQL query that calls the function to perform the cleanup can be called from a daily maintenance script like this:

```
SELECT public.drop_partitions(current_date-180, 'public', 'log', 5, 'day');
```

Which will DROP the YYYY-MM-DD_log tables that are **5** days older than **180** days ago. For an initial run to delete dozens or hundreds of old table partitions, the **5** can be set to a much higher value that achieves the desired effect.

Comment: This helped me today on 2023 and postgres 13. Before checking this answer y ran a DELETE where timestamp<something, and the query took about 20 minutes, lol (hundreds of millions of rows)... only to find at the end that... the size didn't go down! After dropping the partitions the size went down as intended. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I will just delete the records that are older from the master table, something like:

```
DELETE FROM master_table WHERE creation_date < 'today' - INTERVAL '90 days';
```

However my advice is to time this query to run at the most *sleepy time* for the server, like say 5:00am

Answer (score -3):

regarding dropping a partition, The example that follows deletes a partition of the sales table. Use the following command to create the sales table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
  dept_no     number,   
  part_no     varchar2,
  country     varchar2(20),
  date    date,
  amount  number
)
PARTITION BY LIST(country)
(
  PARTITION europe VALUES('FRANCE', 'ITALY'),
  PARTITION asia VALUES('INDIA', 'PAKISTAN'),
  PARTITION americas VALUES('US', 'CANADA')
);
```

Querying the `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` view displays the partition names:

```
acctg=# SELECT partition_name, server_name, high_value FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS;
 partition_name | server_name |     high_value      
----------------+-------------+---------------------
 europe         | seattle     | 'FRANCE', 'ITALY'
 asia           | chicago     | 'INDIA', 'PAKISTAN'
 americas       | boston      | 'US', 'CANADA'
(3 rows)
```

To delete the americas partition from the sales table, invoke the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE sales DROP PARTITION americas;
```

Querying the `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` view demonstrates that the partition has been successfully deleted:

```
acctg=# SELECT partition_name, server_name, high_value FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS;
 partition_name |     high_value      
----------------+---------------------
 asia           | 'INDIA', 'PAKISTAN'
 europe         | 'FRANCE', 'ITALY'
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Why doesn't your partition syntax [appear to match documented Postgres partitioning examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html#Examples)?

Comment: @ecoe for some reason some people search Postgres partitioning but writes [Oracle partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-D3E92FD8-5FE4-4CEA-9CB8-CC9277A74429.htm)