# PostgreSQL: Automating deletion of old partitions

Tags: postgresql

I am using Imperial Wicket's fine automated partitioning function for PostgreSQL http://imperialwicket.com/postgresql-automating-monthly-table-partitions/) to create weekly partitions to store a large amount of data. The database grows by ~100GB per week, so some frequent attention is needed to ensure the server does not run out of disk space.

I have searched SO but cannot find any solutions to automatically drop tables based on disk space thresholds or time periods. Are there any native PostgreSQL solutions or developed functions to automate dropping old partitions, or is this a roll-my-own solution kind of problem?

Comment: Since you are partitioning by a date range, you might want to look at pg_partman. It will be able to semi-automate to your needs and has a lot of built-in functions for partition management.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a roll my own solution kind of problem. Since I am using Imperial Wicket's automated table partitioning function, I used it as the base to develop a new function that can drop partioning tables older than the specified date.

The code is available at https://github.com/stevbev/postgresql-drop-time-series-table-partitions

Usage is similar to Imperial Wicket's syntax and supports day/week/month/year partitioning schemes. For example, to delete table partitions with name 'my_table_name' created with weekly partitioning that are older than the week 180 days ago, execute the SQL statement:

```
SELECT public.drop_partitions(current_date-180, 'public', 'my_table_name', 5, 'week');
```