# Can’t delete master table data postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have an existing table with data.

```
create table work_data(
   id  integer not null,
   work_time timestamp(3) without time zone not null,
   message character varying(64),
   primary key (id)
);
```

I partitioned the table.

```
create table w_work01(
   constraint pk_01 primary key (id),
   constraint ck_01
      check (work_time >= '2019/07/01'::date and work_time < '2019/07/02'::date)
) inherits (work_data);

create index idx_01 on w_work01 (work_time);
```

And insert the data from work_data to w_work01.

```
insert into w_work01
select * from work_data
where work_time >= '2019/07/01'::date and work_time < '2019/07/02'::date)
```

Then dropped the partitioned table.

```
DROP TABLE w_work01;
```

The partitioned table was deleted.
But the data from the master table was remained unchanged.
So I searched and found the query below.

```
ALTER TABLE master_table DROP PARTITION partitioned_table;
```

But when I used this, there was an error.

> syntax error at or near partitioned_table

How can I solve?

Comment: use partition_name instead of partitioned_table which you can find by below command: 

`SELECT partition_name, server_name, high_value FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS;`

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA This is *not* about Oracle. crystal, please show all the statements you executed: how you created the table, how you  dropped a partition and how you found out that the data were still there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053499/postgresql-delete-partition-tables

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I edited my problem.

Comment: @ROHIT KHURANA Thanks for your help. I found this and used it. But there was error like syntax error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never deleted the data from `work_data`, so it is not surprising that it is still there. You created a table, filled it and dropped it, which has a net effect of nothing.

Besides,you used table inheritance, not partitioning.

To oartition an existing table, a possible way to proceed would be:

- create a table like `work_data`, but with

  ```
  PARTITION BY RANGE (work_time)
  ```
- create partitions for the desired ranges
- copy the data to the partitioned table as you do in your question
- drop the original table